# How to clone any data from a widget with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use a social comments widget for my wesbite, and i want to clone some data from the widget and use it as I want in my template.

To clone the data I use this jQuery code:

```
var $button = $('#hypercomments_widget').clone(true);
$('.image_01').html($button);
```

But it does't work.

Please, if this is possible to get done, help me.

Widget code in side HTML:

```
<div id="hypercomments_widget"></div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    _hcwp = window._hcwp || [];
                    _hcwp.push({widget:"Stream", widget_id: xxxxx});
                    (function() {
                    if("HC_LOAD_INIT" in window)return;
                    HC_LOAD_INIT = true;
                    var lang = (navigator.language || navigator.systemLanguage || navigator.userLanguage || "en").substr(0, 2).toLowerCase();
                    var hcc = document.createElement("script"); hcc.type = "text/javascript"; hcc.async = true;
                    hcc.src = ("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https" : "http")+"://w.hypercomments.com/widget/hc/82481/"+lang+"/widget.js";
                    var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
                    s.parentNode.insertBefore(hcc, s.nextSibling);
                    })();
                    </script>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tgza3x4o/1/)

Comment: Provide a working example for what "doesn't work" means... use jsfiddle/codepen/snippet for that.

Comment: Ok, 5 min i will add this

Comment: Next time you should add this before posting :) not after. Questions like this one getting closed quickly (and you are not new to stackoverflow...)

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I just edit it. now there is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tgza3x4o/1/

Comment: Check your console for errors...

Comment: Checked, no errors

Comment: So double check it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you should wait after your plugin loaded fully try to `setTimeout()` 3 seconds (tested).

see https://jsfiddle.net/tgza3x4o/4/

so this is a working solution

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var $button = $('#hypercomments_widget').clone(true);
    $('.image_01').html($button);
    },3000);//3 seconds
```

Comment: great idea. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help you :)